# How to remove a column from dataframe that is 'chr'

Tags: r, dataframe

How to identify which columnname of a dataframe is "chr" in the output of str(dataframe)?

```
 df = read.table(myfile.txt)
 str(df)
```

In other words, How to know the type of each column in a dataframe?> str(df)

```
 >>>str(df)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ gender: Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 2 1 2 2 2
 $ age   : num  51.1 51.5 52.3 54 52.4
 $ Col1  : int  46 47 45 38 41
 $ Col2  : int  38 NA 38 40 27
 $ Col3  : num  0.6 0.4 0.9 0.8 0.8
 $ col4  : int  1 1 1 1 0
```

Comment: It should say right before the "chr" the column name followed by a colon.

Comment: yes but how to get that list?

Comment: Maybe you want `sapply(your_dataframe, class)`

Comment: Well, your sample data doesn't even contain a character column. The first column isn't exactly `chr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> df <- data.frame(V1=letters[1:20], V2=rnorm(20), V3=rnorm(20), stringsAsFactors=F)
> head(df)
  V1         V2         V3
1  a -1.1503207  0.6404503
2  b  0.8197962  0.5596914
3  c -0.9807482 -0.9668770
4  d -0.7739147 -0.0118510
5  e -0.1544853  0.6315314

> names(df)[(1:ncol(df))[mapply(is.character, df)]]
[1] "V1"
```

Based on a suggestion provided above by @Tyler Rinker :

```
> names(df)[sapply(df, class)=="character"]
[1] "V1"
```

If you would like to simply remove chr columns:

```
> df2 <- df[,sapply(df, class)!="character"]
> head(df2)
            V2         V3
1  -1.15032068  0.6404503
2   0.81979620  0.5596914
3  -0.98074820 -0.9668770
4  -0.77391472 -0.0118510
5  -0.15448529  0.6315314
```